# Discord notification badge not showing

Tags: notification

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and the Discord notification badge in the icon tray isn't showing up even though I have enabled the setting in Discord
[image]

Comment: Where did you get Discord from? If installed via snap, the badge won't work, if installed via .deb, it should - at least in theory.